# How to call a change from non-negative to non-positive

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have found the expression "sign change from non-negative to non-positive"; my questions are:
1) is a "change from non-negative to non-positive" a "sign change" ? (a change from non-negative to non-positive would include also a switch from zero to zero which seems strange to call a "sign change");
2) if not, is there an expression to denote a change from non-negative to non-positive?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If the sign changes from $+$ to $-$, or vice versa, then it is called a sign change, regardless of whether the expression is zero or not. For example, $f(x)=x$ has a sign change at $x=0$ and
$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      x & x\leq -1 \\
      0 & |x|<1 \\
      x & x\geq 1 
   \end{cases}$
has a sign change in the interval $[-1,1]$.